# Shell program to extract data from log files

Tags: regex, shell

I will be writing a shell script to go through the log file generated by my application , I need to separate out only function names and minimum info about the call from the logs generated.

Log file format will be - 
`0.0003 636488 +440 -> include_once(/var/www/public/const.php) /var/www/public/ajax_shop.php:2`

Now, out of such line I want to extract that - "include_once" was called at line "2" from the file "ajax_shop.php"

how should I use regular expression in shell script for this situation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using sed:

```
sed 's/.*-> \([^(]*\).*:\(.*\)/\1 was called at line \2/' logfile
include_once was called at line 2.
```

\([^(]*\) => This matches till a closing bracket is encountered. [^(]* => Means a series of characters which is not a '('.

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F"[>(:]" '{print $2 " was called at line " $NF}' logfile
 include_once was called at line 2.
```

awk uses multiple delimiters >,( and :. Using this, it becomes simple just to print the 2nd field and the last field.

Comment: that was a master piece, can you tell me the use of '\' character in regex ? is it used to map multiple instances of matching sting ? not getting the use of '\'.

Comment: \ was used to escape special characters. However, the \1 and \2 are variables used to access the sub-groups which are grouped earlier.

Comment: still m not clear,

`[^(]` => select upto '('

but 

`\([^(]*\)` => ?


sorry for these questions but I am new to this !

Comment: I got the result as expected while using your solution,
but I was trying some code where i used 
`s/-> [^\(]*/\1 is the function name/'` in the sed command but it is giving me error as - ` invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS`

Comment: thank you for the help, worked and got the complete solution as - 

`temp=REUIERED_STRING_FROM_LOG_FILE


echo $temp | sed 's/.*-> \([^(]*\).*\( .*\):\([0-9]*$\)/function \1\n called from \2\n at line number \3\n/'`


it is working as per the requirement, please suggest if any better option is available (just for curiosity). Thanks a lot for `sed`